# Explorer thread blocked when getting property of InternetExplorer object during event

Tags: vb.net, events

I'm looking for help (or suggestions/leads) on the following issue.

This console app:

1. looks for an InternetExplorer object,
2. when found, creates a new ListenerExplorer object
3. in which an event handler is activated (TitleChange)

Now, when you run this application while an explorer (not IE, but a general explorer.exe) is active and you navigate to a folder (this triggers a TitleChange event) **the explorer thread is blocked**. It is not possible to navigate further in explorer until the VB app is closed.

This pause occurs in the TitleChange sub, on the line

```
Console.WriteLine("URL=" + objIE.LocationURL)
```

Getting the LocationURL property outside of the event works fine. Within the event, it blocks the explorer thread. 
What caught my attention is that in Visual Studio's immediate window, on a breakpoint on the line above, i'm unable to access the same property:

```
?objIE.LocationURL
Evaluation requires a thread to run temporarily. Use the Watch window to perform the evaluation.
```

Code:

```
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Sub Main()
    Dim objShellWindows As SHDocVw.ShellWindows = CreateObject(“Shell.Application”).Windows
    If (objShellWindows.Count > 0) Then
        objIE = objShellWindows.Item(0)
        AddHandler objIE.TitleChange, AddressOf TitleChange

        'wait for events until a key is pressed by the user
        Do
            If Not (Console.ReadKey.KeyChar = "") Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TitleChange(title As String)
    Console.WriteLine("TitleChange: " + title) 'works fine
    Console.WriteLine("URL=" + objIE.LocationURL) 'blocks the explorer thread!
End Sub
```

I've Googled for days, but can't fix it... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A console application needs a message loop. 
Solved by creating a Windows Forms Application project in MS Visual Studio instead of a Console Application project.